# Existence of Linear Transformation between 3D line and 2D line

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, euclidean-geometry, inverse, linear-transformations

I am wondering if there **exists** an **invertible linear transformation** between 
a line segment in 3D space and a line segment in 2D space.

[image: Does there exist an invertible map from the red line (left)to the blue line (right)]

Basically, the red line above could be represented by the matrix equation $Ax=b$:

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$b = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0.5 \end{pmatrix}$$

The blue line above could be represented as $Cx=d$:
$$C = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$d = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

I am also interested if there exists any **invertible** transformation that
may not be linear.

Edit: What if instead of the red line, I have a higher dimensional object (say of dimension $k$), and I want to transform that (invertible) onto the $k$ dimension simplex. Do I have to find the vertices of that object in order to do so? Or would the equations describing it suffice.

Comment: Yes, just parameterize both of them...

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you please explain a little bit more? I am a bit confused.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is map (bijectively) and continuously (if you want) each segment to a segment along the 1-d real line. Hopefully it's clear how to do this, if not then let me know and I'll explain. Then by composing one bijection with the inverse of the other you get your desired map from one segment to another. Furthermore, if you introduce a bijection from the segment in 1-d to itself, which may not be linear, then you can introduce this into your transformation formulas and still get your bijection, and now, not necessarily linear.

Comment: :) here we go again, same thing exactly, with algebra vs geometry :)

Comment: @gt6989b I like your answer, I just like to think in terms of mapping every segment in ${\mathbb R}^1$ to a segment in ${\mathbb R}^d$, in an obvious form. I'm kinda weird like that. In any event, +1 for your answer.

Comment: @user2566092 thank you both so much for your help! I wrote my response in the other section.

Answer (score 1):

you can write the 2D one as $(0,1) + (1,-1)t$ for $t \in [0,1]$. Can you do this to the 3D one and then invert?

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry but I am new to parametrizing these lines. To systematically find these parameters, is it necessarily true that I must find the endpoints of the line segments? Also, I am confused as to what you mean by invert. Should I represent the transformation as a matrix? I apologize for my limited math knowledge but I'm very curious to understanding what's going on here!!!

Comment: @AndyYao yes, you take one of the end points (start there when $t=0$) and when $t=1$ you should end up on the other end point...

After you have the parameterization done, your segment become a transformation of $[0,1]$, over which $t$ is defined. Can you then given a point on your segment, produce the corresponding value of $t$, which you can map to the second segment.

Comment: Awesome. This makes perfect sense to me. I think I've figured it out. Thanks a lot!